# Executing scripts in a grails Job

Tags: grails, groovy

I am working on two parts of a program. One that creates small groovy scripts and another that executes them in a Job. Each script is used to convert information from a map to a Domain object. The job will then save the domain object for future use.

Here is a small example.

**Domain**

```
class Report {
    Date date
    Country country
}
```

**Map**

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("date", "2015-04-21 11:31:11");
map.put("country", "United States");
```

**Date Script**

```
String script = "x.date = Date.parse('y-M-d h:m:s', y['date'])"
```

The script is currently executed using Eval.

```
Eval(report, map, script)
```

There are other more complicated scripts that need to look up information and make decisions based on values.

The date script works fine but when the country script executes I get an error.

**Country Script**

```
String script = "import app.Country\nx.country = Country.findByName(y['country'])"
```

**Error**

```
Script1.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class app.Country
```

It seems like the Country class is not getting loaded in the call to Eval. How can I do an import in Eval? Should I use Eval or GroovyShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate a GroovyShell passing as argument the grailsApplication class loader, see the example below:

**Bootstrap.groovy**

```
    Map bindingValues = new HashMap()
    bindingValues.sessionFactory = sessionFactory
    bindingValues.propertyInstanceMap = propertyInstanceMap
    bindingValues.dataSource = dataSource
    bindingValues.ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
    GroovyShell gs = new GroovyShell(grailsApplication.classLoader, new Binding(bindingValues))
    gs.evaluate new File("docs/CargaAvaliacoes.groovy")
```

**CargaAvaliacoes.groovy**

```
    import avaliacao.Colaborador
    import modelo.ModeloAvaliacao
    import programa.Programa

    def programa = Programa.get(1)
    def modelo = ModeloAvaliacao.get(1)

    def avaliadores = ["02270789332":"1020016","11388449681":"1010002","02231772331":"1010004","04247774332":"1020002"]

    def avaliacaoService = ctx.getBean("avaliacaoService")

    avaliadores.each {
            def avaliador = Colaborador.findByCpf(it.key)
            def avaliados = Colaborador.findAllBySetorAndCpfNotEqual(it.value,it.key)

            avaliados.each {
                avaliacaoService.cadastrar(programa, modelo, avaliador, it)
            }
    }
```

** You need to specify the grailsApplication.classLoader because this class loader is used to load the Grails domain classes.